# Angular Bootstrap Tab Icons

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

Is there way way to use Font Awesome icons inside Angular Bootstrap Tab Headers?
http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/tabs

I am only seeing a string option?

```
<tab index="0" heading="Info">
```

Solution:

```
<tab index="0">
<template tabHeading>
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Info
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
<tab index="0">
<template tabHeading>
  <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Info
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `<ng-template>` and then you can place any custom html and give styling if needed.

```
<tab index="0">
 <ng-template tabHeading>
       <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Info
 </ng-template>
</tab>
```